# Confirm alert box in javascript and ASP.net like Hotmail

Tags: asp.net, javascript, button, confirm

i am trying to create a confirm box similar to Hotmail's Confirm box when we click on the Empty Folder in the Junk Mail folder.

but i am unable to figure it's working and the logic behind it.

i am using ASP.Net 2 in VS 2005 Pro.

is there any special logic which goes behind the working of the confirm box like the one used in Hotmail, or a custom control. which works on the basis of button pressed or action taken like OK or Cancel.

Looking for favorable replies.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the Hotmail confirm box you're refering to, but Javascript comes with a `confirm()` function that's easy to use. See [here](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jconfirm.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple confirm box you can do the following:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
             OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
             OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
  Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

That will show a confirm dialog, and the Server-Side Click event will be executed only if the user selects `Ok`.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the above method you can also use the [ConfirmButton extender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) from the AjaxControlTookit to do this. The advantage of the ConfirmButton extender is that it can pop-up a modal window as well as a conventional JavaScript confirm alert.